# Strict warning: Non-static method CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::profileDisplay()

Tags: profile

As administrator I get the following error message:

```
Strict warning: Non-static method  CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::profileDisplay() should not be called statically in CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::profileDisplay() (line 2790 of <host>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php).
```

I know I can suppress such error / warning messages via Drupal and/or amending civicrm setting somewhere. But it is annoying that these messages are there at each transaction. Is there a fix?

Thank you.

David

Answer (score 2):

Can you check if you are on the latest version civi?

To fix your notice, you/a developer need to correct civicrm source code, ie. modify CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php so it doesn't call statically the method, or change the method so it's a static one.

the change in itself is a one line of code, but checking what else is calling that profileDisplay method and if it's always static or some are using it "normally" needs a bit of analysis.

Once you have done that analysis and tested it locally (in a civicrm installed from git), you need to fork civicrm-core, commit your change on your repository and do a pull request

It's hopefully pretty clear in the wiki... and not as complicated as it might sound, come on IRC if you get blocked on your way:
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Contributing+to+CiviCRM+using+GitHub

Answer (score 2):

If you are hitting this on the latest 4.6 you should log an issue in JIRA. It looks like this

public function profileDisplay($gid, $values, $template) {

needs to be changed to

public static function profileDisplay($gid, $values, $template) {

ie
https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm-core/commit/768f4db1f6f150e0dde0700561be378587fa8a3d

I don't see any evidence of this being called from more than one place- but try a quick grep to confirm